# Unable to pull data from a file and place into two arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code uses the `matrix` and `arrpow` functions to calculate the fibonacci numbers for the elements in my list, `num`. Oddly, right after    `a.append(float(row[0]))` is completed, the error I get is

> IndexError: list index out of range

Which is obviously coming from b.append.

Here's the file I want to pull from
[image: Here's the file I want to pull from]

```
import time
import math
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def arrpow(arr, n):
    yarr=arr
    if n<1:
        pass
    if n==1:
        return arr
    yarr = arrpow(arr, n//2)
    yarr = [[yarr[0][0]*yarr[0][0]+yarr[0][1]*yarr[1][0],yarr[0][0]*yarr[0][1]+yarr[0][1]*yarr[1][1]],
            [yarr[1][0]*yarr[0][0]+yarr[1][1]*yarr[1][0],yarr[1][0]*yarr[0][1]+yarr[1][1]*yarr[1][1]]]
    if n%2:
        yarr=[[yarr[0][0]*arr[0][0]+yarr[0][1]*arr[1][0],yarr[0][0]*arr[0][1]+yarr[0][1]*arr[1][1]],
            [yarr[1][0]*arr[0][0]+yarr[1][1]*arr[1][0],yarr[1][0]*arr[0][1]+yarr[1][1]*arr[1][1]]]
    return yarr

def matrix(n):
    arr= [[1,1],[1,0]]
    f=arrpow(arr,n-1)[0][0]
    return f

num = [10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000]

with open('matrix.dat', 'w') as h:
    for i in num:
        start_time = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        run = matrix(i)
        h.write(str(math.log10(i)))
        h.write('\n')
        h.write((str(math.log10(time.time()-start_time))))
        h.write('\n')

a = []
b = []

with open('matrix.dat','r+') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        a.append(float(row[0]))
        b.append(float(row[1]))

plt.plot(a,b,label = " ")
```

Comment: This is also the third method I've tried, so i'm almost positive that the issue lies somewhere in the file.

Comment: In "a.append(float(row[0]))" can you print(row) to make sure row[0] exists?  Is it just an empty list?

Comment: @user2263572 It doesn't print as an empty list. It's printing each number from matrix.dat, in the form: ['float'], followed by the next number on the next line, and so on. I'm guessing it's printing in string form?

Comment: in Python x[0] of string "test" would return "t".  So that wouldn't throw the error. Somewhere in your code you are trying to access an index value that does not exist.  Also, you can always do print(type(row)) to get a better understanding of what row is.  Check that row[1] is a valid index as well.

Comment: @user2263572 yes, so I print(type(row[0]) after a.append, and it threw 12<class string> at me. Then I did the same for [1], and as you said, it's as if it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are constructing `matrix.dat`, you do not add a comma for the CSV reader to separate the data. So when it tries to read the file, the whole thing is converted into a 1-element array. Attempting to access the second element throws an error because it doesn't exist.

**Solution:** Replace \n on line 34 with a comma (,).

Comment: Great, do you have any suggestions to help me minimize my code, especially dealing with the files? For instance, not having to open the same file twice.

Comment: You could squash the file use into one context manager using the r+ mode (meaning you can read and write to it). Otherwise, I would look at a better way to write that arrpow function, it looks pretty dank.

Answer (score 2):

```
row = ['1.0']
```

So row is a list with `1` value.  `row[1]` is trying to access the second index of a list with `1` value.  That is why you are getting an error.